# Operators that are invariant under rotation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, commutator, rotation, invariants

Consider a system described by state $|\psi\rangle(x,y,z)$.
$\hat U_n(\theta)$ is an operator which rotates the wavefunction about an axis $n$ by an angle $\theta$ in positive direction.
$|\psi\rangle(x,y,z)\to \hat U_n(\theta)|\psi\rangle(x,y,z)$
Now consider an operator $\hat O$. So in Heisenberg picture, we can consider wave function to be remain same under rotation and only the operator changes.
So, $\hat O\to \hat U_n^{\dagger}(\theta)\hat O \hat U_n(\theta)$

Now suppose that the operator does not change under rotation.
$\hat O\to \hat U_n^{\dagger}(\theta)\hat O \hat U_n(\theta)=\hat O \tag{1}$.
As $\hat U_n(\theta)=e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat n.\vec{L}}$
$\hat n$ is tje unit vector in the direction of $n-$ axis
$U_n^{\dagger}(\theta)U_n(\theta)=I$.
So, $(1)$ becomes,
$[\hat O, e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat n.\vec L}]=0$
$\implies[\hat O,\hat n.\vec{L}]=0 $
From there it has been concluded that $\boxed{[\hat O,\vec L]=0}\tag{2}$
As $\hat{n}.\vec{L}=xL_x+yL_y+zL_z$.
$x$ amd $L_x$ will commute because $L_x$ is associated with the rotation about $x-$ axis, so $x$ coordinates remains unchanged.

$[\hat O,\hat n.\vec L]= [\hat O,xL_x]+[\hat O,yL_y]+[\hat O,zL_z]$
Each term in the above sum has to go to 0
$[\hat O,xL_x]=\hat OxL_x-xL_x\hat O= 0$
$\implies \hat OL_xx-xL_x\hat O=0 \tag{3}$

From $(3)$, I am not able to understand how to prove $\hat OL_x-L_x\hat O=0$ to reach $(2)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several (minor) things incorrect here.

1. If you use $\vert\psi\rangle$ you should not use $\vert\psi\rangle (x,y,z)$.  Rather, $\psi(x,y,z)=\langle x,y,z\vert\psi\rangle$.
2. $U(\theta)=e^{i\theta \hat n\cdot\vec L}$, with $\theta$ explicit.
3. $\hat n\ne x\hat x+y\hat y+z\hat z$.  This vector is constant (although arbitrary in direction) with length $1$ (which your parametrization does not give) but does not depend on $x,y$ or $z$ since the direction about which you rotate may not have anything to do with the point $x,y,z$ in space (whatever that point is for you).  Normally $\hat n$ parametrized by
   \begin{align}
   n_x=\sin\beta\cos\xi\, ,\quad 
   n_y=\sin\beta\sin\xi\, ,\quad 
   n_z=\cos\beta\, .
   \end{align}
   with $[\hat L_i,n_j]=0$.

More important to your question:

4. Finally, since $[\hat O,\hat n\cdot\vec L]=0$ *for any $\hat n$*, you can *in turn* take $\hat n= \hat x, \hat y$ and $\hat z$ so that
   \begin{align}
   [\hat O,\hat L_x]=[\hat O,\hat L_y]=[\hat O,\hat L_z]=0\, .
   \end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In point (3), you have written the component of $n$ in the spherical coordinates. But we can parameterized in cartesian coordinates also?

Comment: Also, why $[L_i,n_j]=0$?

Comment: It does not matter what you use for parametrization.  The components $n_i$ are constant and independent of the position in space $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: Ok, so basically after defining the axis of rotation the unit vector in the direction of rotation axis also becomes fixed, so is its x,y amd z component. Thus $[L_i,n_j]=0$, because $n_j's$ are constant. Am I correct?

Comment: yes.  You can have a rotation about $\hat z$ at the origin where $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ for instance, or a rotation about $\hat z$ (same $\hat n$) at $(10,-9,31)$…